# ILnumerics c# draw line

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, ilnumerics

How can I add line, like I drew in Paint with ILNumerics?
My scene is building with that code:

```
 ilPanel1.Scene = new ILScene()
 {
     new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false)
    {
        new ILSurface(func,
                     xmin: (float)xmin,
                     xmax: (float)xmax,
                     ymin: (float)ymin,
                     ymax: (float)ymax,
                     xlen: 200,
                     ylen: 200,
                     colormap: Colormaps.ILNumerics),
    }
};
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7BTMmDd.png]

edited:

```
var line = ilPanel1.Scene.Camera.Add(Shapes.Line);
ILArray<float> angles = ILMath.linspace<float>(0, 6, 6);
ILArray<float> pos = ILMath.zeros<float>(1,1,1);
pos["0;:"] = (float)xt; pos["1;:"] = (float)yt;
pos["2;:"] = 0f;
line.Positions = pos;
line.Color = Color.Black;
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an image which explains more than 1000 words

Comment: What is in `line.Positions` after the line `line.Positions = pos`? Keep in mind that you are in Camera space here. You could add the line shape to the plotcube if you need the same coordinates for the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as this:

```
ilPanel1.Scene.First<ILPlotCube>().Add(
    new ILLines(/* do your line setup here */)
);
```

See the documentation of shapes here: http://ilnumerics.net/drawable-nodes-shapes.html

Comment: I'm trying to draw a line with an edited code in the topic but it doesn't draw, can you look at it?